# pandas DataFrame lives in "limbo" when monkey patching its constructor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey patch DataFrame constructor in `pandas`. The return value from the inner scope (inside the patch) disappears - it returns with `None`. Yet, in the outer scope, the DataFrame is constructed as expected, even though the patch return is the apparent `None`

```py
import pandas as pd

f = pd.DataFrame.__init__


def make_df(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Called Before')
    df = f(*args, **kwargs)
    print(f"df from inner scope:\n{df}")
    return df


pd.DataFrame.__init__ = make_df

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('aab'), 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
print()
print(f'df from outer scope:\n{df}')
```

And the result:

```
Called Before
df from inner scope:
None

df from outer scope:
   a  b
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  3
```

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, `__init__` normally doesn't return obj. It doesn't create object. Object already got created by `__new__`. Object is supposed already existed when you call `__init__`.

`__init__` puposes is initializing Objects attributes, so there is no reason to return anything from it. Just pull up any python source code, you will rarely see any `return` command in `__init__`

inside your monkey patch the `__init__` (makedf), your `df` captures the `return` of the original `pd.DataFrame.__init__` which have no `return`. Therefore, it is `None`

Comment: Oh! Yeah I see it now. So it's not even pandas specific.
Just got confused by pandas' long __init__

Comment: yup, it has nothing to do with pandas. It is the python design :)